# F#: Casting to generic type

Tags: generics, casting, f#

I'm fairly new to F# and coming from a C++ background. I am trying to write a simple vector class which can be of generic type (int, float, etc) but I run into trouble with the default constructor. I want to initialize the values to be zero but to do this I need to somehow cast a concrete zero to a generic type but I'm not sure how to do this.

Perhaps some code might help. Here's what I have so far:

```
type Vector3D<'T> (x :'T, y: 'T, z: 'T) = 
    member this.x = x
    member this.y = y
    member this.z = z

    new() = Vector3D<'T>(0,0,0) // what goes here?
```

I have tried many things on the highlighted line but cannot seem to get the compiler to be happy. I tried, for instance, `Vector3D('T 0, 'T 0, 'T 0)` which I thought should cast the `int` zero to `'T` zero but that did not work.

Am I missing something fundamental or is it merely a case of getting the right syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses the built-in generic zero function:

```
type Vector3D<'T> (x : 'T, y: 'T, z: 'T) =
    member this.x = x
    member this.y = y
    member this.z = z

let inline newVector () : Vector3D<_> =
    let zero = Core.LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    Vector3D(zero, zero, zero)

let v1 : Vector3D<int> = newVector ()
let v2 : Vector3D<double> = newVector ()
let v3 : Vector3D<int64> = newVector ()
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that `newVector` is inline?

Comment: @Dan If you look at the type of `GenericZero` its `GenericZero<^T (requires ^T with static member Zero)> :  ^T (requires ^T with static member Zero)`. The important thing to note here is the `^T` instead of `'T` which you normally see. This denotes that the function has a generic constraint which is resolved at compile time. That is, the compiler generates code similar to C++ templates which makes it work. Use of generic member constrains requires `inline` functions.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  Generic zero prevents nulls and restricts the Vector to numeric types.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [`defaultof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee353732.aspx) function:

```
type Vector3D<'T> (x :'T, y: 'T, z: 'T) = 
    member this.x = x
    member this.y = y
    member this.z = z

    new() = Vector3D<'T>(Unchecked.defaultof<'T>, 
                         Unchecked.defaultof<'T>, 
                         Unchecked.defaultof<'T>)
```

Note that if `'T` is a reference type, `defaultof<'T>` will be null. To get around this, you can use a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233203.aspx) to limit `'T` to value types—also known as `struct`'s.

```
type Vector3D<'T when 'T : struct> (x :'T, y: 'T, z: 'T) = 
    ...
```

With this, you will still be able to use this `Vector3D<'T>` with `int`, `float`, `decimal`, and many other commonly used types, but it will guarantee that none of the `x`, `y`, or `z`, members may be null.

Comment: Perfect thanks. It's probably just because I'm used to C++ but generics in F# seem like a bit of a pain.

Comment: @Dan Yeah they're very different concepts. In the case of generics, they must be guaranteed to be type-safe even if resolved at run-time. In this case, the compiler can't be sure there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `'T`.

Comment: This (and the question itself) are a bad idea IMHO. You end up with nulls for reference types. Just don't write a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I considered adding a note on using type constraints to address this. I went ahead and updated my answer for completeness.